# What kind of food is referred to as "sushi" in English?

Tags: word-meaning, connotations

A sequel to [this CAPTCHA question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246580/is-a-hamburger-considered-a-sandwich), but no one posts for me this time so...

[image]

```
legends (image #)
      0
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

It was this test that prevented me from being a human, for I couldn't find any other sushi in images above. (The image #0 is a sample, and I already ticked off #4, where I saw multiple sushi on the dish in the middle before it shrank a little.) Some users said that #1 looked like sushi, which is, in Japanese sense of word, nothing but [*unadon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unadon), a dish with plain rice and grilled eel, and is distinct from sushi.

Do English speakers perceive #1 or other ones as (or are reasonably confused with) "sushi", or should I just blame Google? I don't want to believe a hamburger is a sushi as well as a sandwich :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the "correct" answer was?

Comment: @Catija Not yet. I'm trying to get the same question from CAPTCHA but...

Comment: #1 appears to be Japanese food of some sort; it's pretty likely it was accidentally selected as being sushi, either by an automated search or a less than astute programmer.

Comment: I got this one recently. I believe it was #1. It is such a poor photo; I thought the front middle item might be a California roll but that is just a guess. Anyway by process of elimination it couldn't be any of the others.

Comment: I do not believe this question is off topic. Please actually **read the content of the question** before saying it's asking a "Basic question on spelling, meaning or pronunciation".

Comment: I believe that generally, American English speakers conflate "sushi" and "sashimi" unless they have some experience to teach them the difference. If it has raw fish and/or has rice rolled up in seaweed, we'll probably call it "sushi'.As for the CAPTCH, I think William Kappler is right. (1) looks like it might have sushi in it, but it's a bad image.

Comment: @user3169 - I agree with you; it's certainly not 6, 8, or 9! This makes me wonder if the CAPTCHA technology is designed to eventually drop questions with a low success rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely 1 is the other "sushi" they are looking for. My guess is that the images were automatically selected by an image search. #1, given it is Japanese food, might have come from a page that also discussed sushi, and was thus misidentified as containing it.